# DataGridView listing selected item from ListBox

Tags: c#, database, linq, data-binding, datagridview

On my form1 there is a listbox listing the movies from database(bindingsourced).

On my form 2 i placed a datagridview and would like to show the data of the selected movie from listbox on form1.

```
BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();
bindingSource1.DataSource = from s in db.Filmek where s.Filmcim == (string)f.lBfilmlista.SelectedValue select s;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
```

The problem with my code above that it only lists the first movie all the time whether i select other movie or not from the listbox on my form1. How should i do that to show the selected item from listbox all the time?

Answer (score 0):

Put the same code into selected Index change event of the listbox......

its because this datasource will be call just for one time (In the begining)

If you use selectedIndexChange event of listbox every time datasource will bind and you will get what you need....

All the best

Comment: can you help me how to do that? they are on different forms. If i make an extract method from the code above it is not working in the form1 ofc. How can i make it compatible?

Answer (score 0):

Take one property in Form1 and assign listbox selected value to that property 
On list selected index changed event open the Form2

on Form2 load use Created property that u created in form1

For Example u created Property: sValue

Then your query will be like this

```
BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();
bindingSource1.DataSource = from s in db.Filmek where s.Filmcim == (string)form1.sValue select s;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
```